# Arabic text not connected when specifying stroke width

Tags: flutter, dart, arabic

Arabic text is not connected when I specify a stroke width. Here's what I see:

[image]

The connections within the circled portion shouldn't be there, but instead each character should be connected, like in cursive text. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Text.rich(TextSpan(
            text: 'كيف الحال',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 80,
                foreground: Paint()
                  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                  ..strokeWidth = 2
                  ..color = Colors.blue))));
  }
}
```

If I use `PaintingStyle.fill` instead of `PaintingStyle.stroke` above, I don't see any issue because the text is filled in.

How can I get rid of these connections? Is there a way to merge paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stack another Text widget that just colors the text, then the connections between two letters is hidden:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Text('كيف الحال',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 80,
                    foreground: Paint()
                      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                      ..strokeWidth = 2
                      ..color = Colors.blue)),
            Text('كيف الحال',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 80,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

You must stack because Flutter only allows specifying one of color/foreground/background.

If the color has transparency, then the connections are shown. So my question isn't fully addressed, but I don't need transparency.